# What is a good substitute for oyster sauce (for someone with a shellfish allergy) that is also allergic to mushrooms?

Tags: substitutions, allergy, shellfish

I just started to teach myself to cook some Chinese food recipes however a great deal involve oyster sauce. When trying to look up alternatives everything kept saying a form of mushroom sauce. Problem is I'm highly allergic to mushrooms as well. What is a good substitute?

Comment: Hello Saige! I see that your problem is a bit more specific than the one in the older question. But out of the four answers there, three don't involve mushrooms. So I think it's reasonable to see it as a duplicate.

Comment: @rumtscho The answers to the referenced question call for mushrooms or fish sauce, neither of which will work for the OP.

Comment: @Cindy of the 4 answers, only one says "mushroom sauce". The answer with fish sauce will work equally well or badly independent of an added mushroom allergy. So it *is* the same question, with only one of the answers not applicable. No need to have a second question which will have to repeat the same answers bar one.

Comment: @rumtscho Of the 4 answers: One mentions mushroom sauce, one says to use vegetarian oyster sauce (which is made with mushrooms), and one uses fish sauce (which would be questionable for someone with a shellfish allergy). I'm not trying to be argumentative, I was just hoping that someone could answer this question more specifically.

Comment: @Cindy you are welcome to cast a reopen vote, which will put the question in the reopen queue, and then others can reopen it. I just don't see why eventual new answers should go into this question here when they can go into the other one, so that all relevant information is kept in the same place.

Comment: @Cindy I would also like to cast a reopen vote but unfortunately don't have the reopen to do so. This is not a duplicate, for the reasons you mention.